# Modal Loop in a GTK+ application

Tags: user-interface, gtk, modal-dialog, event-loop

I am trying to write a function which will wait till the user clicks somewhere within a GTK+ widget (similar to a drawing area) and return mouse co-ordinates. This function should behave modally in that it waits till input is received. Those familiar with the Windows API may find some similarity to the [`TrackPopupMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which also waits till a menu item is selected.

What I am trying to do here is similar to running a "secondary message loop" using the Windows API. How is it done in GTK+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);` to "pump" the GTK+ event system, without (the `FALSE`) blocking the application.

Comment: Are there any problems in calling gtk_main again followed by gtk_main_quit once the job is done? As an example, I want to write a function which prompts the user to select a point within the client area. I set up a signal handler for button-press-event and call gtk_main. In the handler, once the point is selected, I save the point somewhere and call gtk_main_quit causing the innermost gtk_main to return. Is this advisable?

Answer (score 0):

Being modal is possible for a GtkWindow, using [gtk_window_set_modal](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-modal), not for a GtkWidget. That makes sense, otherwise the user wouldn't know what to interact with if there wasn't a window poping up.

Comment: In this case, I am not using a modal window. I just want a function which behaves modally. The function prompts the user to select a point and does not return till the point is selected.